# AngularJS - AngularController not getting the content inside RenderSection, mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a problem with rendering an MVC view with sections and angularjs controllers.

The problem is that the content inside the sections in the index-view is not included inside my controller. So if i do some angular stuff inside the partial views that is loaded width RenderSection, it will not work with the controller wrapping the sections.

Do any of you smart people out there have a solution to my problem, or maybe i should render the views in a different way?

If more information is needed, please comment and i will provide! :)

PS. It's worth mentioning that the reason the setup is like this, is because of the content's placement on mobile vs desktop

Layout(_root)

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="div2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
                @RenderSection("TopMenu", false)
            </div>
            <div class="div1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div class="div3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 mainrightside">
                @RenderSection("RightSide", false)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Index:

```
<div ng-controller="angularController">
@section TopMenu{
    @Html.Partial("PagePartials/xxx", Model)
}
@section RightSide{
    @Html.Partial("PagePartials/xxx", Model)
}
@Html.Partial("PagePartials/xxx")</div>
```